# i want to add next page (every page is 10) to my recyclerview but it delet my last page

Tags: android-recyclerview, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines, endlessscroll

**my recyclerview fragment:**
this is the fragment that I set my recycler view , I want when touch  the continue button (btn_continue) add the rest of the list, which is actually  the next page, to my list when I click the button
But it deletes the previous list and displays the new list
and i use the kotlin coruotine, viewmodel and recyclerview

```
 class AllUnpublishedAdsFragment : Fragment() {
          
            lateinit var unpublishedAdsAdapter: UnpublishedAdsAdapter
               var items = ArrayList<M_Ads>()
               lateinit var loadMoreItems: ArrayList<M_Ads>
               lateinit var scrollListener: RecyclerViewLoadMoreScroll
               lateinit var mLayoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager
               val page = "1"
               var newpage = page.toInt()
           
               var navController: NavController? = null
               lateinit var btn_continue: Button
               private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewmodels
               lateinit var token: String
           
           
               override fun onCreateView(
                   inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                   savedInstanceState: Bundle?
               ): View? {
                   // Inflate the layout for this fragment
                   return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_unpublished_ads, container,
   false)
               }
           
               override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                   super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
                   btn_continue = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_continueAds)
                   token = arguments?.getString(TOKEN_KEY).toString()
                   Log.i("TOKEN", token)
                   setupViewModel(token, page)
           
                   continueAds()
           
           
           
           
                   unpublishedAdsAdapter.itemClickListener = { item, position ->
                       val id = item.id
                       val bundle_id = Bundle()
                       bundle_id.putString(ID_KEY, id.toString())
                       navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)
                       //view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_UnpublishedAds_to_Detail,
   bundle_id)
                       navController!!.navigate(
                           R.id.action_allUnpublishedAdsFragment_to_adsDetailFragment,
                           bundle_id
                       )
                   }
               }
           
               private fun setupViewModel(token: String, page: String) {
                   LoadingDialog.show(requireContext(), { ld ->
                       recy_unpublished_ads.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
                       val decoration = DividerItemDecoration(activity, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL)
                       recy_unpublished_ads.addItemDecoration(decoration)
                       viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewmodels::class.java)
                       unpublishedAdsAdapter = UnpublishedAdsAdapter()
                       recy_unpublished_ads.adapter = unpublishedAdsAdapter
                       viewModel.adsListObserve().observe({ lifecycle }, { model ->
           
                           items.clear()
                           items.addAll(model.adsList!!)
                           unpublishedAdsAdapter.setUpdateData(items)
                           ld.dismiss()
                           btn_continue.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                       })
                       viewModel.getAdsList(token, page)
           
                   })
               }
           
                   fun continueAds() {
                   var isTouched=false
                   btn_continue.setOnClickListener {
                       isTouched=true
                       newpage = newpage + 1
                       Log.i("CONTINUE", newpage.toString())
                       setupViewModel(token, newpage.toString())
                       unpublishedAdsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                       isTouched=false
                   }
               }
```

**RetrofitInstance class**

```
class RetrofitInstance {

    companion object{

        fun getRetrofitInstance (): Retrofit{
//            val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
//            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
//            val client: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build()
            val okHttpClient: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build()

            return  Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASEURL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build()
        }
    }
}
```

**my adapter:**

```
class UnpublishedAdsAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<UnpublishedAdsAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    var items = ArrayList<M_Ads>()
    var itemClickListener: ((item: M_Ads, position: Int) -> Unit)? = null
    lateinit var mcontext: Context

    class ItemViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
    class LoadingViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    fun setUpdateData(items: ArrayList<M_Ads>) {
        this.items = items
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }



    class MyViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val img_ads = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.img_recy_ads)
        val txt_title = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt_recy_ads_title)
        val txt_accountType = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt_recy_ads_acctype)
        fun bind(data: M_Ads) {
            txt_title.setText(data.title)
            txt_accountType.setText(data.accountType)
            if (!data.image1.equals("")) {
                Picasso.with(img_ads.context).load(data.image1).into(img_ads)
            } else {
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {

        mcontext = parent.context
        return if (viewType == Constant.VIEW_TYPE_ITEM) {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.row_recy_unpublished_ads, parent, false)
            MyViewHolder(view)
        } else {
            val view =
                LayoutInflater.from(mcontext).inflate(R.layout.progress_loading, parent, false)
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                view.progressbar.indeterminateDrawable.colorFilter =
                    BlendModeColorFilter(Color.WHITE, BlendMode.SRC_ATOP)
            } else {
                view.progressbar.indeterminateDrawable.setColorFilter(
                    Color.WHITE,
                    PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY
                )
            }
            MyViewHolder(view)
        }

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(items.get(position))
        handleClick(holder)

    }

    fun handleClick(holder: UnpublishedAdsAdapter.MyViewHolder) {
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val position = holder.adapterPosition
            itemClickListener?.invoke(items.get(position), position)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }
```

**my Viewmodel:**

```
class MainViewmodels:ViewModel() {
    lateinit var getAds:MutableLiveData<Main_ModelAds>
    init {
        getAds= MutableLiveData<Main_ModelAds>()
    }
    fun adsListObserve():MutableLiveData<Main_ModelAds>{
        return getAds
    }
    fun getAdsList(token:String,page:String){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                Log.i("ERRORRES",token + "")
                val retrofitInstance=RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(RetrofitService::class.java)
                val response=retrofitInstance.unPublishedAdsList(token,page)
                getAds.postValue(response)
            }catch (ex:Exception){
                Log.i("ERRORRES", ex.message.toString() + "")
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want here is to update the list that you are showing when the user clicks the button.
In this case you should use ListAdapter.

You can refer to this article for implementation:
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter